# why does ThreadPoolExecutor execute method runs same task twice whereas submit method runs it once correctly in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Greetings of the day!!!

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Java for performing some task using the `Execute(Runnable task)` method. I am submitting two task, say `task A and task B`, but `task A` is never performed and `task B` is performed twice by two different threads.
For this i tried to use `Submit(Runnable task)` method and it performs both the tasks once properly.
Can somone please help me understand why in `Execute` method threads are picking up the same task twice and while in `Submit` method it picks both tasks wait for the completion of `A` and then executes `B`.
Sample code below for ref:
here if I make a call to `class A asyncProcess` twice for two task(A & B) to execute then only B gets run twice and if i simply replace `execute` method with `submit` method (`Future<?> Future = asyncTaskExecutor.submit(task)`)then both task will run properly. I might be wrong or not having proper in depth knowledge where I'm going wrong or missing something, Please help me with the understanding.

```
public class A {

    
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor;

    public void asyncProcess(Map<String, String> requestData, String module, String action) {
        
        Task task = new Task(requestData, "task_name", module, action );
        try{
            asyncTaskExecutor.execute(task);
        }catch(TaskRejectedException e){
            logger.error("Email Notification Task Rejected, manually running task",e);
            task.run();
        }
    }
    
    
private class Task implements Runnable {
        

        
        private Map<String, String> requestData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        private NotificationRequest notificationRequest;
        
        private String Msgtype; 
        
        private String module;
        
        private String action;
        
        public NotificationTask(NotificationRequest notificationRequest, Map<String, String> requestData, String type){
            this.requestData = requestData;
            this.notificationRequest = notificationRequest;
            this.Msgtype = type;
        }
        
        public NotificationTask(Map<String, String> requestData, String type, String module, String action){
            this.requestData = requestData;
            this.Msgtype = type;
            this.module = module;
            this.action = action;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean exceptionOccured = false;
            try{
                if(Msgtype.equalsIgnoreCase("task_name")) {
                    System.out.println("completing task");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error( e.getMessage() );
                exceptionOccured = true;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's hard to see what's wrong if we have nothing to see.

Comment: BTW, the "exception occurred" stuff you have here is essentially wheel reinvention: make it a `Callable` instead, and it can throw a checked exception. Then you get the result from the `Future` returned by the executor.

Comment: @Andy Turner noted, thanks.